# app not working

Tags: android

i have written a simple app which would speak out to the user any incoming message. Both programmes seem to work perfectly when i lauched them as two separate pgms , but on keeping them in the same project/package only the speaker programme screen is seen and the receiver pgm doesn't seem to work . Can someone please help me out on it?

the speaker pgm is:

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech; 
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

// the following programme converts the msg user to speech

public class TextSpeaker extends Activity  implements OnInitListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
public TextToSpeech mtts;
public Button button;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The service has been started\n Every new   message will now be read out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

    });
    Intent myintent = new Intent();
    myintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(myintent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data)
    {
     if(requestcode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
     {
      if(resultcode==TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
      {
       // success so create the TTS engine
       mtts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
       mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

      }
      else
      {
       //install the Engine
       Intent install = new Intent();
       install.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
       startActivity(install);
      }
     }

    }
    public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceStatBundle)
    { 
     mtts.shutdown();
    }

    public void onPause()
    { 
     super.onPause();
     // if our app has no focus
     if(mtts!=null)
      mtts.stop();
    }
 @Override
 public void onInit(int status) {
 if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
  button.setEnabled(true);

}


}
```

and the Receiver programme is:

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage; // supports both gsm and cdma
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str="";
if(bundle!=null)
{
// retrive the sms received

Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
{
msgs[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
str+="Message From "+msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()+".";
str+="Message "+msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
}
Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
TextSpeaker tsp  = new TextSpeaker();
tsp.mtts.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);

}

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you've merged the manifest files correctly? Is there anything relevant shown in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `tsp.mtts` is null. You're directly creating a new instance of `TextSpeaker` instead of the activity being created properly by the OS, so there's no reason its `onCreate` method would be called, so `mtts` will never be initialised.

Comment: ok, so can you please suggest how do i correct it, actually i am quiet new to android

Comment: i tried to correct it by writing TextSpeaker tts; just after the onReceive method and then removed the instance creating statement. and simply had tsp.mtts.speak(..) , still it shows same runtime error? is there some other way of doing it?